# Matrix division & permutation to achieve Baker map

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to implement the Baker map. 
Is there a function that would allow one to divide a 8 x 8 matrix by providing, for example, a sequence of divisors 2, 4, 2 and rearranging pixels in the order as shown in the matrices below?

```
X = reshape(1:64,8,8);
```

After applying divisors 2,4,2 to the matrix X one should get a matrix like A shown below.

```
A=[31 23 15 7 32 24 16 8;
  63 55 47 39 64 56 48 40;
  11 3 12 4 13 5 14 6;
  27 19 28 20 29 21 30 22;
  43 35 44 36 45 37 46 38;
  59 51 60 52 61 53 62 54;
  25 17 9 1 26 18 10 2;
  57 49 41 33 58 50 42 34]
```

The link to the document which I am working on is:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.5132&rep=rep1&type=pdf

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are the divisors supposed to do? What about all the approaches one can find on google?

Comment: What if there is no answer on google. I would have provided an image if I had been allowed to.

Comment: Post a link to an image, and someone will post it for you =) Btw: I have no idea what the logic is...  How do you achieve the `A` matrix?

Comment: @AndriusRickus It's just that everything one can find googling "baker map matlab" doesn't look trivial, and it appears that there is no simple answer to your question. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: a little more generic solution:**

```
%function Z = bakermap(X,divisors)
function Z = bakermap()
X = reshape(1:64,8,8)'
divisors = [ 2 4 2 ];

[x,y] = size(X);

offsets = sum(divisors)-fliplr(cumsum(fliplr(divisors)));

if any(mod(y,divisors)) && ~(sum(divisors) == y)
    disp('invalid divisor vector')
    return
end

blocks = @(div) cell2mat( cellfun(@mtimes, repmat({ones(x/div,div)},div,1),...
                                           num2cell(1:div)',...
                                          'UniformOutput',false)         );

%create index matrix
I = [];
for ii = 1:numel(divisors);
     I = [I, blocks(divisors(ii))+offsets(ii)];
end

%create Baker map
Y = flipud(X);
Z = [];
for jj=1:I(end)
    Z = [Z; Y(I==jj)'];
end


Z = flipud(Z);
end
```

**returns:**

index matrix:

```
I =

     1     1     3     3     3     3     7     7
     1     1     3     3     3     3     7     7
     1     1     4     4     4     4     7     7
     1     1     4     4     4     4     7     7
     2     2     5     5     5     5     8     8
     2     2     5     5     5     5     8     8
     2     2     6     6     6     6     8     8
     2     2     6     6     6     6     8     8
```

Baker map:

```
Z  =

    31    23    15     7    32    24    16     8
    63    55    47    39    64    56    48    40
    11     3    12     4    13     5    14     6
    27    19    28    20    29    21    30    22
    43    35    44    36    45    37    46    38
    59    51    60    52    61    53    62    54
    25    17     9     1    26    18    10     2
    57    49    41    33    58    50    42    34
```

---

But have a look at the if-condition, it's just possible for these cases. I don't know if that's enough. I also tried something like `divisors = [ 1 4 1 2 ]` - and it worked. As long as the sum of all divisors is equal the row-length and the modulus as well, there shouldn't be problems.

---

**Explanation:**
% definition of anonymous function with input parameter: div: divisor vector

```
blocks = @(div) cell2mat( ...          % converts final result into matrix
                cellfun(@mtimes, ...   % multiplies the next two inputs A,B
                repmat(...             % A...
                {ones(x/div,div)},...  % cell with a matrix of ones in size
                                         of one subblock, e.g. [1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1]
                div,1),...             % which is replicated div-times according 
                                         to actual by cellfun processed divisor
                num2cell(1:div)',...   % creates a vector [1,2,3,4...] according
                                         to the number of divisors, so so finally
                                         every Block A gets an increasing factor 
               'UniformOutput',false...% necessary additional property of cellfun
               ));
```

Have also a look at [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20683310/4) to have a simpler insight in what is happening. You requested a generic solution, thats the one above, the one linked was with more manual inputs.

Comment: Could you write a solution for a square matrix of any size and for any sequence of divisors? It would be brilliant if the solution would be according to the formula on the page 1264 in the given document.

Comment: Well I'm not a slave, and I'm not reading your document. Have a look at my last edit. That should be good enough for the most cases. Otherwise it's a good starting point for you. Anyway, I'm off for christmas holiday now ;)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain this statement step by step?  blocks = @(div) cell2mat( cellfun(@mtimes, repmat({ones(x/div,div)},div,1),num2cell(1:div)','UniformOutput',false)); Many Thanks

Comment: And apart from that, this question is now lost in transit, people need to search for it. By asking a new question (a good one!) you get the attention of other users.